# ¿Es correcto meter un evento dentro de otro evento?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un script en el cual voy agregar archivos XLS, una vez que valido el formato del archivo, cierro un modal de bootstrap y abro otro modal donde es una ventana de confirmación para ver si esta seguro de subir ese archivo.

Este modal de confirmación tiene un botón de confirmación, una vez hecho clic quiero que me ejecute una función donde correra un AJAX para hacer la petición al servidor.

Sin embargo, a causa de eso, me surgieron las siguientes dudas:

- ¿Cuál de las 2 maneras es mejor (y lo más correcto) ejecutar el código y porqué?
- ¿Por qué se ejecuta el evento clic del primer input file si no ha habido un event change?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Primer input file
  $(document).on('change','#file', function(){
    let file = $(this);
    let nameFile = file[0].files[0].name;
    let button = '<button type="button">Clic input 1</button>';
    
    $('#button').html(button);
    
    $('#button').click(function(){
      console.log('CLICK IN FIRST INPUT FILE!');
    });
    
  });
  
  //Segundo input file
  $(document).on('change','#file2', function(){
    let file = $(this);
    let nameFile = file[0].files[0].name;
    let button = '<button type="button">Clic input 2</button>';
    
    $('#button2').html(button);
  });
  
  $('#button2').click(function(){
      console.log('CLICK IN SECOND INPUT FILE!');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
<div id="button"></div>

<div style="margin-top:20px"></div>

<input type="file" id="file2" name="file2"/>
<div id="button2"></div>
```

Comment: los dos ejemplos que tienen son lo mismos codigos no veo diferencia

Comment: Creo que la respuesta a tus preguntas se responde ejecutando tu código de ejemplo para el siguiente caso: `Selecciona un archivo, has clic en el botón. Selecciona otro archivo, has clic en el botón`. Vas a ver que para la **`primer forma` existe el problema que se acumulan eventos por cada vez que se realiza un `change`**. Ahora te pregunto yo, ¿es correcto dicho comportamiento?

Comment: voté para cerrar tu pregunta porque se basa en opiniones, no en algo mesurable objetivamente.

Answer (score 5):

Respondiendo directamente a tu pregunta

> ¿Es correcto meter un evento dentro de otro evento?

Si es correcto, el truco está en saber cuando debes hacerlo y cuando no. Primero considera que existen varios tipos de eventos, no sólo el `'click'`, que pueden cumplir distintas funciones.

*¿Cuando es una buena práctica?*

**Cuando se hace de forma controlada.**

Un ejemplo es el evento [ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) que solo se desencadena cuando se carga la página. Intentar vincular un evento antes que este se desencadene puede traer como consecuencia que la página no haya cargado del todo, el objeto al que intentas adicionarle el evento (click) no está disponible aún y tu código falla. El hecho que este evento sólo se desencadena una sola vez garantiza que no se agregarán más eventos `click` por accidente al mismo elemento.

> Siempre evita crear eventos indiscriminadamente ya que eso sólo conduce a fugas de memoria y al mismo código ejecutandose una y otra vez.

Los eventos consumen memoria y es muy fácil perderles la pista ya que es difícil saber, por ejemplo, [cuantos eventos de un tipo tiene asociados un elemento determinado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008592/can-i-find-events-bound-on-an-element-with-jquery)<sup>1</sup>. Ademas su uso indiscriminado puede conducir a que se ejecute el mismo código varias veces sin que te des cuenta.

Te pongo un ejemplo donde sí puedes hacerlo; Si el botón al cual le estás intentando añadir el evento no existe todavía y se crea como resultado de la ejecución del primer evento. En ese escenario la unica alternativa es crear el elemento primero para poder añadir el evento después.

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    const button2 = $('<button>Click me</button>');
    button2.click(function() {
        // Haz algo
    });
    $('#placeholder').append(button2)
});
```

Otra alternativa que si es muy similar al código expuesto es cuando el contenido del evento se genera a partir de un algoritmo determinado (que depende del input del usuario por ejemplo), algo así como un *factory* de eventos. En ese caso siempre recuerda desvincular los eventos que ya hayas agregado anteriormente.

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    const data = $('#input').val()
    const button2 = generaBoton(data);
    const evento = generaEvento(data);
    button2.click(evento);
});
```

En cualquier caso es importante recordar que los eventos pueden (y deberían) desvincularse si se almacena la función con la que los generaste

```
let evento = null;
const button1 = $('#button1');
const button2 = $('#button2');
button1.click(function() {
    // Si ya se generó lo eliminas para que no se duplique
    if (evento) {
        button2.off('click', evento)
    }
    // Conservas una referencia al evento
    evento = function() {
        // Haz algo
    };
    button2.click(evento);
})
```

Muchas veces se usa la sintáxis `$(selector).off('evento')` como válvula de escape para eliminar todos los de un tipo sin tener que almacenar la función pero el uso de ese mecanismo requiere precaución ya que podrías terminar eliminando otro que no quieras eliminar (recuerda que puede ser otro evento además de `click`).

Corrigiendo tu ejemplo primero debo señalar que a quien le estás vinculando el evento no es al botón sino al `div`. El evento se ejecuta de todas formas por que este hace burbuja desde el botón al `div`. Prueba a cambiar

```
// Inserta el botón como contenido del div
$('#button').html(button);
```

por

```
// Inserta el botón fuera y justo después del div
$('#button').after(button);
```

y comprueba que efectivamente nada ocurre al presionar click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Primer input file
  $(document).on('change', '#file', function() {
    let file = $(this);
    let nameFile = file[0].files[0].name;
    let button = '<button type="button">Clic input 1</button>';

    $('#button').after(button);

    $('#button').click(function() {
      console.log('CLICK IN FIRST INPUT FILE!');
    });

  });

  //Segundo input file
  $(document).on('change', '#file2', function() {
    let file = $(this);
    let nameFile = file[0].files[0].name;
    let button = '<button type="button">Clic input 2</button>';

    $('#button2').html(button);
  });

  $('#button2').click(function() {
    console.log('CLICK IN SECOND INPUT FILE!');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
<div id="button"></div>

<div style="margin-top:20px"></div>

<input type="file" id="file2" name="file2" />
<div id="button2"></div>
```

Si arreglamos el código

```
//Primer input file
$(document).on('change', '#file', function () {
    let file = $(this);
    let nameFile = file[0].files[0].name;
    // No almacenes una cadena sino que crea un elemento html
    let button = $('<button type="button">Clic input 1</button>');

    $('#button').html(button);

    // Agrega el evento al boton creado, no al div
    button.click(function () {
        console.log('CLICK IN FIRST INPUT FILE!');
    });

});
```

observarás que el problema desaparece y es porque al remplazar el contenido del `div` tambien destruyes el botón y por consiguiente liberas el evento. Esta es la razón por la que al crearlo de nuevo sólo se desencadena una sola vez.

Si aún así deseas ejecutarlo en un elemento que no vas a destruir (por ejemplo el `div` como lo tenías anteriormente)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Primer input file
  $(document).on('change', '#file', function() {
    let file = $(this);
    let nameFile = file[0].files[0].name;
    let button = '<button type="button">Clic input 1</button>';

    $('#button').html(button);

    // Elimina el evento antes de agregar uno nuevo
    $('#button').off('click');
    $('#button').click(function() {
      console.log('CLICK IN FIRST INPUT FILE!');
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
<div id="button"></div>
```

y el problema desaparece pero considerando que ahora sabes la causa es evidente que la segunda variante en tu código original es preferible ya que te ahorras el paso de desvincular y vincular el evento para cada click en un elemento que siempre se encuentra disponible y por consiguiente es algo que puedes hacer una sola vez.

<sup>1</sup> Esto depende de código interno de jQuery y no deberías usarlo nunca en producción. Podrías actualizar la versión y que este código deje de funcionar.

Answer (score 4):

La segunda forma es la correcta porque estás agregando un `listener` a un `div` una sola vez, en la primera defines un `listener` distinto cada que cambia `#file`:

```
$(document).on('change','#file', function(){ //cuando file cambie
 let file = $(this), nameFile = file[0].files[0].name;
 $('#button').html('<button type="button">Clic input 1</button>'); //el contenido del div #boton será un botón.

 $('#button').click(function(){ //cuando se haga click en el DIV #button
   console.log('CLICK IN FIRST INPUT FILE!'); //manda a log este string
 });
});
```

Dicho de otro modo, se enviará un log a consola **N** veces por cada click en 
`#button` donde **N** es igual al número de veces que hayas cambiado #file.

Por otro lado, en el segundo caso el `listener` de`#button2` será definido una sola vez al ser llamado por `$(document).ready()`. Sin importar cuantas veces cambies `#file2` en consola solamente aparecerá 1 lína de log por cada click en `#button2`.

```
//Segundo input file
$(document).on('change','#file2', function(){ //cuando file cambie
 let file = $(this), nameFile = file[0].files[0].name;
 $('#button2').html('<button type="button">Clic input 1</button>'); //el contenido del div #boton será un botón.
});

$('#button2').click(function(){
 console.log('CLICK IN SECOND INPUT FILE!');
});
```

En todo caso podría sugerir que hagas un botón y luego agregues el `listener` a ese botón en lugar del `DIV`:

```
//Sugerencia
$(document).on('change','#file2', function(){ //cuando file cambie
 let file = $(this), nameFile = file[0].files[0].name, id = 'boton' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
 $('#button2').html('<button type="button" id="' + id + '">Clic input 1</button>'); //el contenido del div #boton será un botón.
 $('#' + id).click(function(){
  console.log('CLICK IN A BUTTON INSTEAD OF A DIV!');
 });
});
```

Otra forma puede ser definiendo la función en el botón:

```
...
 $('#button2').html('<button type="button" onclick="logConsole(this)">Clic input 1</button>'); //
...
function logConsole(a){
 console.log(a);
 console.log('CLICK IN BUTTON WITH A FUNCTION DEFINED ONCLICK!'); 
}
```

Al final todo depende de que quieres lograr con tu diseño.

Comment: tu respuesta es correcta Solrac, pero tambien se lograria pasando una variable global a true. digamos que tienes una variable global llamada ´var isReady = false´ y que su valor cambia a true cuando se detecte un cambio en dicho input

Answer (score 1):

No metes un evento dentro de un evento. Es decir, en el primer caso le sigues diciendo a JQuery que ejecute el código SIEMPRE que se haga click en un elemento con id 'button'. La segunda manera, en mi opinión, es la correcta. Si quieres ejecutar un evento, prueba con `trigger(evento)`.

Otro apunte sobre `<div style="margin-top:20px"></div>`. Nunca dejes un elemento vacío para dejar un espacio vertical. Prueba a poner este estilo en uno de tus botones o pon un `<div>` con holgura vertical y alinea al centro verticalmente el botón.